# iPad iOS 6.1.3 suddenly very weak wifi signal

Tags: ios, ipad, network, wifi

After upgrading to iOS 6.1.3 a while ago, my iPad's wifi signal (reception) suddenly became very weak. The iPad basically can't find the (source) wifi if it's like 5-7 meters away. I'm sure the (source) wifi has no problems because everyone else's iPads are working fine with that public wifi.

I've tested that the iPad is still functioning by creating a wifi hotspot with a MacBook.

What else can I do to diagnose the problem?

Comment: WiFi issues can have a lot of causes, but in your case it seems that other iDevices can connect without problems while you can't. Did you restart the iPad as well as the hotspot already?

Comment: @patrix Yes, that's always #1 thing when it comes to fixing electronics.

Answer (score 1):

I would ask if you can definitely link the introduction of the poor signal to the time *immediately* after installing the upgrade.  They may be linked, they may not.  If you think there is a link, then I would advise backing up the iPad, and reapplying the OS update via a full restore, thus essentially imaging the entire OS from scratch rather than relying on the OTA upgrade from 6.1.2.

After a re-image, then to rule out any configuration issues, try to connect to the WiFi source without restoring your data.  If it works, then perform a restore and check again.  If it's still not working, then my hunch is that maybe you have accidentally caused the wifi antenna connection to disconnect internally - serious question, can you identify any faint *rattle* type noise if you shake it, particularly in the bottom right where the cable connects.